# Cannot wrap react-autocomplete element in react-redux-form control

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-redux-form

I'm attempting to wrap react-autocomplete's component with a React Redux Form control, but I'm having issues.  Here is what I have:

```
const typeaheadComponent = (props: any) => (
  <Autocomplete
    getItemValue={(item: string) => item}
    items={this.getOptions()}
    renderInput={(props: any) => (
      <input type="text" {...props} />
    )}
    renderItem={(item: string, isHighlighted: boolean) => {
      <div key={uuid.v4()}>{item}</div>;
    }}
    value={value}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onSelect={this.onSelect}
    inputProps={{
      onKeyUp: this.onKeyPress
    }}
  />
);

return (
  <Control.text
    component={typeaheadComponent}
    mapProps={{
      value: props => props.modelValue
    }}
    model={model}
    id={model}
    value={value}
    persist
  />
);
```

}

When I render just the `<Autocomplete>` element (not wrapping it in a RRF control), it functions properly.  When I wrap it in a RRF Control with the code above, though, and focus on my textbox and press a key, the RRF `rrf/clearIntents` action fires, but nothing else.  Also, focus on the input blurs after each press of the keyboard.

I've reviewed the RRF [custom controls](http://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/custom-controls.html) documentation, but I'm still struggling to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in `mapProps` property. According the documentation:

> One important thing to keep in mind is that there is no single value
>   for a ; rather, there are two types of values (that are
>   equivalent, more often than not):
>
> modelValue - the exact value of the model in the store's state
>   viewValue - the displayed value of the model in the component's state
>   For example, if a text control has updateOn="blur", its viewValue will
>   represent what is being typed in the input, whereas the modelValue
>   will represent the persisted value, once the input is blurred.
>
> Because of this, you will want to map the viewValue to a custom
>   control's value if you wish to externally update the value

Here is the working example of using react-autocomplete with react-redux-form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Control, Form, actions } from 'react-redux-form';
import Autocomplete from 'react-autocomplete';

class UserForm extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Form model="user">
        <label htmlFor="user.firstName">First name:</label>
        <Control.custom
          component={Autocomplete}
          model="user.firstName"
          id="user.firstName"
          controlProps={{
            getItemValue: (item) => item.label,
            items: [
              { label: 'apple' },
              { label: 'banana' },
              { label: 'pear' }
            ],
            renderItem: (item, isHighlighted) =>
              <div style={{ background: isHighlighted ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }} 
                   key={item.label}>
                {item.label}
              </div>
          }}
          mapProps={props => ({
            value: props.viewValue,
            onSelect: value => props.onChange(value),
            onChange: props.onChange,
            inputProps: {
              onBlur: props.onBlur,
              onFocus: props.onFocus,
              onKeyPress: props.onKeyPress,
            }
          })} />

        <label htmlFor="user.lastName">Last name:</label>
        <Control.text model="user.lastName" id="user.lastName" />

        <button type="submit">
          Finish registration!
        </button>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

export default UserForm;
```

Working demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y1v7zy9lw).

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I'm trying to check out the demo, but the form component you created (and store?) is not loading.

Comment: @im1dermike Sorry for that. I've updated the demo link.